# How to change values in a dataframe efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

```
# Incorporate delisting return
i = 0
for tc, col in dlret.iloc[:,0:50].iteritems():
    idx = col.index[col.notnull()]
    if len(idx) != 0:
        tr = idx[0]
        val = col.ix[tr]
        #ret.ix[tr, tc] = val #this line is too slow
    i += 1
    if math.floor(i/10) > math.floor((i-1)/10):
        print i
```

The dlret DataFrame is of 600 or so rows and 25000+ columns. I iterate through the columns to look for the first nonnull value (the delisting return) and then find the corresponding location in the ret DataFrame to set the value to that of the delisting return. However, the code runs painfully slow using ix to index the corresponding location. Any suggestion on how to efficiently achieve this?

Comment: Any affinity to pandas dataframe. If not then look at numpy arrays. They are fast

Comment: I think a simple `combine` or `update` function might solve your problem here. Would you mind uploading a sample of your dataset via dropbox sharelink or google driver? If data is proprietary, replace them with some random numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, what you want is **iterate through the columns to look for the first non-null value** for each column and update the ret DataFrame.
You can do this with following code:

```
mask_first_nonnull = dlret.notnull() & (dlret.notnull().cumsum()==1)
ret[mask_first_nonnull]=dlret[mask_first_nonnull]
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion. What I meant was first nonnull value. Thanks for your answer! Also, what I want is to update the ret Dataframe using the dlret Dataframe data, not the other way around.